# Creating users with modified home directory and mask

Tags: users, useradd

I need to create 6 new users (one, two, three, four, five and six) with passwords, two of these (five and six) must have their personal directories modified (using skelo or configuration files, I don't care) and also change the mask for permissions.

Is it possible to make each user creation with these features in a single line?

Comment: What's the reason for your "in a single line" restriction? Any set of shell commands can be written in a single line.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed wrong @they, I simply mean if this can be done using a single command (with useradd itself, for example).

Comment: First of all, what operating system are you using? Second, if Linux, which LInux? What command do you use to create a single user? What have you tried so far and how did it fail? We need to know this so we don't give you things you know don't work for you. Then, what does "have their directories modified" mean? Modified how? And what umask settings do you want? Please [edit] your question and add some detail.

Comment: For only two users that need modification, is it really worthwhile to look for a global solution instead of editing only two `.bashrc` files and giving a single `chmod` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useradd` does not support setting the `umask` value. There is an option for overriding the `UMASK` from `/etc/login.defs` but it only refers to the permissions for the home directory.

So I guess there is no chance for getting this done with a single (well known) command.

It does not seem reasonable to me but you could add code to the general shell init files (e.g. `/etc/bash.bashrc`) which sets `umask` based on the home directory permissions (or better, creates just once a respective entry in the user config file). This is obviously not a good idea if it may happen that the passed `umask` value is more permissive than you want the home directory to be.